# Node.js update element in mongodb array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following Mongoose schema and model:

```
//GameBoards
var gameBoardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  mCurrentPlayer: Number,
  mCurrentPlayerName: String,
  mStarted: Boolean,
  mSwitching: Boolean,
  mFinished: Boolean,
  mPlayers: [{mPlayerId: String, mUsername: String, mHand: [{mValue: Number, mSuit:     String}], mFaceDown: [{mValue: Number, mSuit: String}], mFaceUp: [{mValue: Number, mSuit: String}], mPosition: Number, mSwitching: Boolean}],
  mDeck: [{mValue: Number, mSuit: String}],
  mPile: [{mValue: Number, mSuit: String}],
  mStartedAt: {type: Date},
  mLastUpdate: {type: Date},
  mChanceTaken: Boolean,
  mRoundLenght: Number,
  mNumberOfPlayers: Number,
  mLocked: Boolean
});
var GameBoard = mongoose.model('gameBoard', gameBoardSchema);
```

I already have a gameBoard in my database with four players. Now I'm trying to update a specific player in the database with the following command:

```
GameBoard.update({_id: game._id, "mPlayers.mUsername": updatedPlayer.mUsername}, {$set: {"mPlayers.$": updatedPlayer}}).exec();
```

But this does not seem to be working, but I get no error =/. I have tried to do a find with the same parameters and that works like a charm. Can someone pin point what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it seems like there is no problem finding the game itself.  When I do a callback and print out  the found item for update it prints out my game. So the problem should be in the {$set: {"mPlayers.$": updatedPlayer}

Comment: this works fine in the shell so there are two possibilities - there is some issue with "updatedPlayer" structure you are trying to set the array element to, or Mongoose isn't handling something correctly.  Try printing out what updatedPlayer is and then doing this update in mongo shell  - if that works, then Mongoose is the problem.

Comment: I tried some different things and it seems like mongoose doesn't like the $. When I'm doing "mPlayers.1" it works like a charm :)

Comment: what if you want to update a document that's different element of the array?

Comment: var value = {};
value['mPlayers.' + counter] = updatedPlayer;
models.GameBoard.findOneAndUpdate({_id: game._id}, {$set: value}).exec();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some different things and it seems like mongoose doesn't like the $. When I'm doing "mPlayers.1" it works like a charm :)